# How to get index/position of excel column in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, math, calculated-columns

I am developing a program where I need to find out index/position of given excel column's index.

if I passed `A` it should return 1

if I passed `AA` it should return 27

if I passed `AB` it should return 28

if I passed `AAA` it should return 26*26*26 (not sure but want to get actual position)

what I did so far

```
var str = "AB";
            var d = 0;
            for (var i = 1, m = 26; i < string.length ; i++) {

                if(string.length === 1) {
                    var d = parseInt(string.charCodeAt(i) - index);
                } else if (string.length === 2){
                    var d = parseInt(((string.charCodeAt(i) - index) * m ) + (i));
                } else {
                    var d = parseInt(((string.charCodeAt(i) - index) * m ) + (i));
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "MM19";
            var number_regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g;
            var matches = [];
            str.replace(number_regex, function (match) {
                    matches.push(match);
                });
            str = str.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
            matches.push(str);

            console.log(matches[1]);

            var index = 64;

            var string = matches[1];

            var columnIndex = 0;
            var counter = 0;
            var baseValue;
            var m = 26;
            console.log("length is:", string.length);
            for (var i = string.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                columnIndex = columnIndex + (string.charCodeAt(i) - index) * Math.pow(m, counter);
                counter++;

            }
            console.log("index value", columnIndex);
```